# How to integrate Twitter4j with fragments in Android?

Tags: android, integration, fragment, twitter4j

I am new to fragments as well to Twitter4j. I found couple of tutorials to use Twitter4j with activity but none with fragments. How can I use Twiter4j with fragments in Android.

If possible I am looking for a example and tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Here you get the idea to integrate Twitter http://android10.org/index.php/articleslibraries/291-twitter-integration-in-your-android-application...

Comment: Thank you for the help... but this link shows me how to integrate the twitter4j with activity... which I have already done.. but I want to integrate with fragments.. and there is nothing called onNewIntent in fragments so I stuck...